Many-To-One relation with both side's navigation properties defined does not work
I have two entities:
Order and OrderItem. Order has many OrderItems and an OrderItem belongs to one Order. The key columns in the database are INTs, but the key in EF is the guid column. The database schema (SQL Server) is quite old, so we have to work with that.
Order-Table: (int) id, (Guid) guid, ...
OrderItem-Table: (int) id, (Guid) guid, (int) OrderId, ...
Configuration for Order:
oBuilder.HasKey(o => o.Guid)
oBuilder.HasMany(o => o.OrderItems).WithOne().HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id).HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId);

Class:
class Order
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Guid Guid { get; set;}
   public IList<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

Configuration for OrderItem:
oiBuilder.HasKey(oi => oi.Guid)
oiBuilder.HasOne(oi => oi.Order).WithMany().HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id).HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId);

class:
class OrderItem
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Guid Guid { get; set;}
   public int OrderId {get; set;}
   public Order Order {get; set; }
}

Doing a query against Order with context.Orders.Include(o => o.OrderItems) raises this exception:

'Invalid column name 'OrderGuid'becaus EF tries to Join on the key column(ON [o].[GUID] = [oi].[OrderGuid])

It ignores my configuration (because it should use [oi.OrderId] as configured). Interestingly, EF does two queries even if it would't be necessary (I'm using AsSplitQuery):
SELECT [o.GUID],[o].[Id]
FROM [Order] AS [o]

SELECT [oi].[GUID], [oi].[Id], [oi].[OrderGuid], [oi].[OrderId], [o].[GUID]
FROM [Order] AS [o]
INNER JOIN [OrderItem] AS [oi] ON [o].[GUID] = [oi].[OrderGuid]
ORDER BY [oi].[Id], [o].[GUID] 

But if I remove the Order property from OrderItem (and the EF configuration) it works, the second query then does look like this (see the missing OrderGuid column):
SELECT [oi].[GUID], [oi].[Id], [oi].[OrderId], [o].[GUID]
FROM [Order] AS [o]
INNER JOIN [OrderItem] AS [oi] ON [o].[Id] = [oi].[OrderId]
ORDER BY [oi].[Id], [o].[GUID] 

Adding this navigation property with or without configuration leads to this exception.
What am I missing? The query works without problems as long as OrderItem has no property Order. For other queries I need that property so I can load OrderItems with a condition on their Order, but by Guid not by Id.

Which one is the key? The Id or the Guid?

In EF the guid is the key, but in the database all tables are joined on the ids.

One of the two configurations is redundant. If you keep the one for Order, use WithMany(o => o.OrderItems).

EF should match your DB.

@GertArnold I know, but removing one of the configurations doesn't change anything

@GHDevOps In an ideal world, yes. But I'm stuck with it as is, and this is working fine, just not in this simple case.

So I found the solution.
I had to specify the property on the other side in the fluent configuration (in the WithOne / WithMany):
oBuilder.HasMany(o => o.OrderItems).WithOne(oi => oi.Order).HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id).HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId);

oiBuilder.HasOne(oi => oi.Order).WithMany(o => o.OrderItems).HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id).HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId);


You don't need both configurations. They're complementary and EF will only pick one of them. The other one is redundant and, therefore, should be removed. It doesn't matter which one.

To configure bi-directional references you don't configure either side:
// Order
oBuilder.HasMany(o => o.OrderItems).WithOne().HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id).HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId);

and
// OrderItem
oiBuilder.HasOne(oi => oi.Order).WithMany().HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id).HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId);

You configure one side with the bi-directional reference:
// Order
oBuilder.HasMany(o => o.OrderItems)
    .WithOne(oi => oi.Order)
    .HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId);

... removing the extra config on the OrderItem. HasPrincipalKey is used for relationships where the FK does not marry up with the PK on the primary table. If you are linking to the PK then don't bother adding it.
Edit: It doesn't make much sense why Order.Guid and OrderItem.Guid would be set up in EF as the "Key" when the PK is Id in the DB, however if that cannot be changed then you can use the HasPrincipalKey() in the configuration. Only one side needs to be configured. (Multiple sides can be configured but if for any reason they get out of sync you can end up with confusing mapping errors)
// Order
oBuilder.HasMany(o => o.OrderItems)
    .WithOne(oi => oi.Order)
    .HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderGuid); // Link the redundant Guid foreign "key" to what EF thinks is the PK (order.Guid)

or
// Order
oBuilder.HasMany(o => o.OrderItems)
    .WithOne(oi => oi.Order)
    .HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id)
    .HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId); // Link the real int PK/FK

Your original configuration was trying to configure two completely separate many-to-one relationships and trying to tell EF to use the same FK for both of them. I.e. "Order has many OrderItems but there is no Order on the OrderItem." and "OrderItem has an Order, but it has no OrderItems collection." "Oh, but use the same FK for both of these separate relationships." That doesn't make sense to EF.

I have to set the FK with .HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId) because the keys in the EF Model are the Guids, but Ids in the database. And removing the reference configuration for OrderItem doesn't help, same error.

In Order and OrderItem, remove the HasKey(oi.Guid).. EF's "Key" should match the table's PK.

I can't change the keys. It's an existing project which I only extend. But I found the solution and posted it.

Yeah, some devs do weird things with EF. You still only should map the relationship from one side or the other rather than both. You can use the HasPrincipalKey to map oi.OrderId to the order.Id instead of what EF recognizes as the PK (Guid). Or you can use HasForeignkey(oi.OrderGuid) which will marry it up with the PK EF is using. (o.Guid)
